# a socket fd has been called "shutdown", can I "reopen" it?

Tags: linux, sockets, shutdown

We know a socket fd can be partially closed by "shutdown()" function. My question is, is there an API to reopen either read peer or write peer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The shutdown as per standard initiates a FIN request to the peer. Thus, the communication will be shut down at both sides of the connection. Also, even if you manipulate so, that the FSM of the local TCP stack is switched back to the state where respective communication is allowed/supported, the peer will not handle this.

Look here: http://tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPOperationalOverviewandtheTCPFiniteStateMachineF-2.htm

Comment: `shutdown()` only shuts down one side of a connection, unless you specify both.

Comment: I like the mention of FIN. +1.

Comment: Not all shutdowns send FINs. Only SD_WRITE does that. @linuxfan

Comment: @EJP Right, only SHUT_WR and SHUT_RDWR do. The interesting point is that, after a FIN has been sent, there are _two_ hosts which change state (in their finite state machines). Your answer below is correct, but it is not simply a matter of API, the whole TCP protocol should be changed to allow that.

Answer (score 1):

> a socket fd has been called “shutdown”, can I “reopen” it?

It isn't closed. However it is certainly shut down, in one direction or the other, or both, and there is no API to undo that.